# Why persist permissions in the db?

Tags: design-patterns, database-design

Lets assume we have following two roles for a given application: User and Admin

User has following permissions: ReadUser, UpdateUser
Admin has following permissions: ReadUser, UpdateUser, CreateUser, DeleteUser

Most of the applications I have worked upon persists both the roles and permissions to the db as follows:

Role
(RoleID, RoleName)
(1, User)
(2, Admin)

Permission
(PermissionID, PermissionName)
(1, CreateUser)
(2, ReadUser)
(3, UpdateUser)
(4, DeleteUser)

RolePermission
(ID, RoleID, PermissionID)
(1, 1, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(3, 2, 1)
(4, 2, 2)
(5, 2, 3)
(6, 2, 4)

My question is what is the benefit around persisting permissions to the db compared to having map of roles with permissions in the code to handle permissions?

I would appreciate if you can elaborate the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this question is correct for stackoverflow.com

Permissions - it is nothing more than a kind of configuration, which might be changed at runtime by no-programmers. If a manager or customer needs an ability to change something, he should not have programming skills for it. It must not be required to code something, and probably rebuild the code. For instance to add another role, which combines permissions from non-related roles.

Keeping persistent configuraiton allows to archiev it. It could be sql-storage, no-sql storage, cloud storage, configuration file. Every storage has its own pros and cons. You could change the configuration via GUI, or at least at runtime, without code change/rebuild/redeployment.

In certain cases roles/permissions could be hardcoded in the code, for instance to control functionality in gui. If user has no `create user` permission, he should not see the button. So keeping persistent data does not exlude using the configuration attributes, like properties, constants in the code.

That's how I would explain to my kinder, the purpose of external and persistent configuration:)